# Using Drush to update Drupal 6 core on multisite installation

Tags: 6, drush, multi-sites

I'm running multiple sites on a single Drupal 6 installation. I'd like to use drush to update Drupal core to the latest version without having to unlock update.php via settings for each site and then going to update.php for each of the different urls (there are over 10 sites).

Is there a drush command to update drupal core and run update.php for all sites at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one single command to do it but we use a bash script that follows this pattern:

1. ls sites folder for all directories
2. pass resulting output to `drush -l $variable sql-dump > /home/user/backup/$variable.sql`
3. pass resulting output to `drush -l $variable updb --yes`

Hope this helps.

Comment: That answers my question, digital, thanks. And thanks for sharing your script. In short then, I really just need to write a script that finds the site directories in the site folder and calls the drush -l {siteurl} updatedb command.

Comment: Yeah pretty much, it's crude but effective.